# unable to update sql server using data obtained from facebook login, using php and js

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-login

tried a bit but unable to detect the error, what i want is when a user visits my site and logs in using facebook login, his user data must be added to my site's database.

Below is the client js side code, this works correctly and obtains data from Facebook, i verified by printing the obtained details. but after adding AJAX to post to php file, even the "thanks for loging in" message is also not printed

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 var url = '/me?fields=name,email';
         FB.api(url, function (response) {  //over here i used this to obtain email explicitly
             var fbname=response.name;
             var mail=response.email;
             $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "http://kumarindia.byethost24.com/addguestbook.php",
             data: "name="+fbname+"&email="+mail,
                 });
   document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name  +"," + response.email + '!';
});
}
```

now the server side php file is below,

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comment']);


$sql="INSERT INTO questbook (name, email, comment, datetime)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$comment', '$datetime')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Try using an object instead of a query string: `data: {name: fbname, email: mail}` And remove the trailing comma.

Comment: Will it affect, if the php file has a comment parameter but the object doesn't supply it?

Comment: Might be, yes. You should check for that. Example: `$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['comment']) : '';`

Comment: and what do you think is preventing the "thanks for logging in..." message from being shown

Comment: tried all changes, still no change in the database

Comment: Can you put a console.log right after the line `FB.api(...`? Does it print something to the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58259/discussion-between-jeroen-noten-and-n0062eclipse).